# What does モンロス mean?

Tags: meaning

> アニメ放送も終了してモンロスに悲しむ世帯主の方々へ朗報

What does モンロス mean? It seems to be used as a na-adjective, but I couldn't find the meaning anywhere.

Comment: 〜ロス, such as あまロス or 五代ロス, are slangs based on ペットロス症候群(animal loss https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_loss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear first the word "モンロス" but we recently use the word "～ロス" , which means " the lost of something. For example, ペットロス means " the thing one lose one's pets."

I research the comment of your sentence, so I get モン is a omission of a comic "モンスター娘のいる日常", so モンロス means " the lost of  "モンスター娘のいる日常".

アニメ放送も終了してモンロスに悲しむ means "the people who weep for モンロス by ending the anime."

Comment: This is illuminating. So, it is a japanese idiom that dictionaries do not teach.

Comment: @crocket It's not an idiom... it's Internet slang specific to a small subcommunity. I point this out because we are all language learners here, and "idiom" isn't the proper English word. :)